# Download Image from byte stream c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to save the image from the URL [link](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1yRnXjREIZ8wJ2ACfaAVyZGIuJDvLfNP-olu45HGAv8UtF3e7PL3T2bf2lEqHcT61nU=s180-rw) and display it on UI then

I tried all the approaches I was able to google for that purpose:

```
 PictureBox pb = new PictureBox(); 
 pb.Load(imageUrl);
```

and

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
{
        byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(imageUrl);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms); 
}
```

and more...

But unfortunately, I'm constantly getting `ArgumentExceptiom` "Parameter is not valid, no matter what way I use to convert byte stream to the `Image`

P.S. You can open the link in browser -> it is public.

**UPDATE**:
Issue was resolved by just removing `-rw` at the end of the link

Comment: The Bitmap class (GDI+) doesn't support the WebP image format. But you can find some NuGet packages that do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your File is `.WebP File`, and `Bitmap class` doesn't support the WebP format.

A bitmap consists of the pixel data for a graphics image and its attributes. There are many standard formats for saving a bitmap to a file. GDI+ supports the following file formats: BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG, and TIFF. For more information about supported formats, see [Types of Bitmaps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/types-of-bitmaps)

Comment: Hah, things are ridiculously easy, when you know how to deal with them. Thank you, sir!